# Create a report with grouped header

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I have a data export in the following format:

```
Address 1 | Person 1 | Status
Address 1 | Person 2 | Status
Address 1 | Person 3 | Status
Address 2 | Person 1 | Status
Address 3 | Person 1 | Status
Address 3 | Person 2 | Status
```

I’m trying to turn this into a report where the address is used to group people and their status under neat:

```
|      Address 1    |
| Person 1 | Status | 
| Person 2 | Status |
| Person 3 | Status |
|      Address 2    |
| Person 1 | Status | 
|      Address 3    |
| Person 1 | Status | 
| Person 2 | Status |
```

I have tried creating this format using a pivot table but no luck. Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a pivot.

First select your data and create a pivot, put all the fields in the Rows section like below.
[image]

Then on the persons item, click the little arrow and select field settings.

[image]

And then finally select show item in tabular form.

[image]

And you get the output you wanted

[image]